# Number of times button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I am counting the times the button is clicked but on the third time I want to exit from the function. In my code it's not exiting after the third click. Any ideas?
Thanks
In the html page;

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>



 <script>
       var count = 0;

       function myFunction(){

         count = count + 1;
         alert(count);  

      if(count == 3){
  //exit the function but it's not doing that and keeps on counting.
       return;
       }

         }
    </script>
```

Comment: If you `return` out of the function it merely means it stops executing. Next time you click the button it will get executed again, however. What exactly is the goal here - stop counting or stop executing the function? Or is this an XY problem by any chance?

Comment: It's working for you? https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/drfeg3wk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the conditional above the alert. Every time the button is clicked, you're calling the function, which alerts the count before it checks the whether it should return.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>



 <script>
       var count = 0;

       function myFunction(){

           if(count == 3){
               //exit the function but it's not doing that and keeps on counting.
               return;
            }
            count = count + 1;
            alert(count);  
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just move the if block to the beginning of the function.

```
function myFunction(){
   if(count == 3){
       //exit the function but it's not doing that and keeps on counting.
       return;
   }
   count = count + 1;
   alert(count);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function keep counting because you keep calling it. You could do something like this:

```html
<button onclick="count < 3 && myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

On each click you are 'exiting' the function, that is, it is always executed and the return is after the alert so it is always shown.
You can move that up or you can simply remove the onclick attribute and the function won't even be called, assuming your button's id is `btn_3_click`:

```
document.getElementById('btn_3_click').onclick = null;
```

will remove the `onclick` listener

Answer (score 0):

this is what you are currently doing. When you click on the button, you are calling the function, myFunction() which is correct. however, every time you click the button, you are effectively just calling the function over and over again, which means that even after you get to the value 3, when you press it again, it is going to repeat the function, and then progress to the value 4...5....6.. etc. 
It is exiting the function, except since you are calling the function again, for the 4th time, it is still going to increment again and again.

Look up how to make a "disable clickable button". I just did this which works. As you can see, I have given the button an id of myBtn, and then when the value is equal to 3, I disable the button. (Note, the === to indicate that I am also checking that the increment is also an integer type)

```
<button onclick="myFunction()" id = "myBtn">Try it</button>

 <script>

     var count = 0;
     function myFunction(){

        count = count + 1;
        alert(count);  

        if(count === 3){
      //exit the function but it's not doing that and keeps on counting.
          document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
          }

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep in mind that the function associate to the `onclick` event is called every time you click on your button. Your function is actually returning as expected. But your `if` block at the end of it is useless. Indeed, if count is equal to 3, you will enter inside and return. If it's not, you will return immediately, which produce the same result.

If you want to stop counting after the third click, you can either return from the function just at its beginning when your counter is higher than 3 or remove the call to the function when a click event occur, just after the third call.

Here is a minimal example of the second solution (https://jsfiddle.net/57saxtdr/)

*Html*

```
<button onclick="count(this)">test</button>
```

*Javascript*

```
var i = 0;

function count(btn)
{
  i ++;
  alert(i);

  if(i >= 3) btn.onclick = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem exists with your structure.  Technically, you exit the function every time you click the button.  I added a disable line and changed the logic a little to help you out.

```html
<button id="specialButton" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
       var count = 0;
       function myFunction(){
         count = count + 1;
         alert(count);  
      if(count >= 3){
     document.getElementById("specialButton").disabled = true;
       return;
       }
         }
</script>
```

You will see that upon the third click, your button disables itself.

Answer (score -2):

Every time you click the button, you already exit the function and return `undefined`.

Try `count = 0` inside of the `if` statement.